# Increasing the FPS when capturing video from Webcam in obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webcam, video-capture

When trying to capture video from any webcam through `QTCaptureMovieFileOutput` of `QTCaptureFileOutput` classes there is low FPS. As I understand, it's the result of this classes forsing webcam to push high-quality frames, and finally USB speed not enough to stream higher than 1080p video =). With `QTCaptureVideoPreviewOutput` and setting resolution below the maximum worked good, but setting even very low relolutions via using `setMaximumVideoSize:` to `QTCaptureMovieFileOutput` don't work. So is there an easy way to solve this problem?